# Please warn me when my edit to a comment via flag is too long

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, comment-flags, character-limit, warning

When editing a comment from a comment flag on a site where I am a mod, I exchanged a rude word for a polite word. Apparently that pushed the comment over the character limit. The edit went through and end of the comment was trimmed.

I request that the 'edit' not be allowed, and a warning come up in the flag edit field saying "too many characters" or something like that. Just like if I tried editing the comment in the comments section of a post. I wouldn't want important info to be trimmed off the end (especially with no revision history).